# TensorFlow - Split and Squeeze

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and I'm formatting some data to feed into a Recurrent Neural Network. My data is given by a 3d tensor fed into the placeholder `x`. I want to split `x` along the 3rd dimension, and for this I have (note that `n_timesteps` corresponds to the length of `x` along the 3rd dimension):

```
# Split the previous 3d tensor to get a list of 'n_timesteps' 2d tensors of
# shape (batch_size, features_dimension)
x = tf.split (x, n_timesteps, axis = 2)
```

Although, as I have tried with `numpy`:

```
x = np.split (x, n_timesteps, axis = 2)
```

If the `x` is a 3d `ndarray` then `np.split` will return a list of `n_timesteps` arrays with dimension 3, such that the 3rd dimension is singleton. With `numpy` I know that I can easily solve this using `np.squeeze` together with a list comprehension to remove the singleton dimension:

```
x = [np.squeeze(a, axis=2) for a in np.split(x, n_timesteps, axis=2)]
```

But how can I do the same on TF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the squeeze function of Tensorflow (tf.squeeze) and the scan function of Tensorflow (tf.scan) instead of a list comprehension.

```
tf.scan(lambda a, x_i: tf.squeeze(x_i, [2]), x, initializer=tf.constant(0, shape=[n_dim0, n_dim1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for the [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) op:

```
x = tf.unstack(x, axis=2)
```